# Detect failure of shell exec unzip on PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec, unzip

so I have this code:

```
$destination = "/dest";
$filepath = 'filepath.zip';
$ret = shell_exec("unzip " . escapeshellarg($filepath) . " -d " . escapeshellarg($destination) . ";
```

My question is, how do I reliably know in PHP whether or not the unzip operation succeeded or if it ended up encountering some error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shell_exec` will return the output of unzip.

Adding -q parameter to unzip will suppress output, you can set to suppress all messages except errors and if `$ret` length not equal to 0 then the operation didn't complete successfully.

`unzip -tq archive.zip` will output only if the archive is OK or not. You can run this command first, check the output in PHP and run the extraction afterwards if successful.

Comment: hey thanks man. how do i do this though "you can set to suppress all messages except errors "